# Derivatives of convolution in $ \mathbb{R}^n $

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, convolution

I am trying to prove that if $f \in C_c^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g$ is Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the derivatives of $f * g$ equal
$$D^\alpha(f * g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(D^\alpha f)(x-y)g(y)dy$$
and are continuous for all multi-indexes of order up to $k$.

I know the version for $\mathbb{R}$, however I am interested in this $n$-dimensional generalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since $f\in C_c^k$, you have that $D^{\alpha}f\in L^{\infty}$, and thus, $|D^{\alpha} f(x-y) g(y)|\leq \|D^{\alpha} f\|_{\infty} |g(y)|\in L^1$. Thus, the desired simply follows from the dominated convergence theorem for differentiation under the integral, since for every fixed $y$,

$$
D^{\alpha}( f(x-y)g(y))=D^{\alpha}(f)(x-y)g(y)
$$

Comment: Note that continuity of these derivatives also follows from dominated convergence.

Comment: Why is $D^\alpha f \in L^\infty$? I know that $f \in L^\infty$.

Comment: $D^{\alpha} f$ is continuous, since $f\in C^k$ and there exists a compact set $K$ such that $f|_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus K}\equiv 0$. Clearly, for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus K,$ we also have $D^{\alpha} f\equiv 0$ so $D^{\alpha} f\in C_c$. Any continuous function with compact support is $L^{\infty}$.